# Why in .NET this in button handler references parent instead of button?

Tags: javascript, .net

In javascript DOM `this` refers to the element clicked which seems more logical than in .NET where `this` refers to the parent. Why this choice?

The button is also a class. If it was truly OOP it would consider button as first class citizen also. So It's not a question of paradigm here it's rather a question of implementation. My hypothesis is that was probably easier for MS to do so because the physical module exists for parent not for child.

But for us it is a pity since you have to cope with this sender which seems as it is foreign to the button whereas it is himself !

Comment: C# (or VB.Net) is an object oriented language, and 'this' (or 'Me') means the current instance of a class (tipically the current page). is a different language, with a different paradigm, that resides on a different level. they're not comparable...

Comment: The button is also a class. If it was truly OOP it would consider button as first class citizen also. It's not a question of paradigm here it's rather a question of implementation that is probably easier for MS to do so because the physical module exists for parent not for child.

Comment: @user310291, you are wrong here.  This has nothing to do with OOP.  The fact that .NET **IS** OOP dictates that it **cannot** remap "this" to point to the button.  "this" **always** points to the object that holds the method which acts as the handler.  And in >99% of the cases, the handler methods resides in an object that is different from the button.  There really are not a lot of cases where the button will have a method that handles its own events.

Comment: So, in other words, the reverse is true.  .NET cannot point "this" to the button **because** it is OOP.  JavaScript can because it is **not** OOP.

Comment: "And in >99% of the cases, the handler methods resides in an object that is different from the button." Well it's because you use THEIR button not a custom button :) It's always the rest of % that is a problem.

Comment: Javascript is OOP it is not class OOP but prototypical OOP.

Answer (score 3):

They are different systems and different paradigms.

In .NET, your handlers are passed a "sender" argument which contains the object.  The handlers reside in the form object or user control, so "this" refer to that class (if you do a double-click type of adding a handler).  If you manually created the handler, then it can be part of any object (not necessarily the form object), and "this" will map to different things. .NET events are also *not* bubbled or captured.

In DOM, your handlers are *not* passed a "sender" argument.  However, "this" refers to the object.  In DOM, events can bubble or captured.

There is no reason why the designer of JavaScript cannot provide a "sender" argument though, and map "this" back to the object holding the handler.  In my opinion, these were just historical choices being made when the world was much simpler.

Comment: I know that it is passed as sender :) But it wouldn't need to if this was refering to button class. Sender is weird since we are in the button and since sender is like a foreign variable whereas it is himself

Comment: In .NET, all methods are attached to *some* object.  Therefore, "this" in any method **only** refers to the object that owns the method.  It is impossible to redefine this behavior to remap "this" to point to, say, the sender object.  That's because .NET is an object-oriented system.  On the other hand, JavaScript is **not** an object-oriented system.  It does **not** have "classes".  All methods are simply functions, and functions are simple objects.  They do not have to be "attached" to some object to form "methods".  Therefore, JavaScript is free to remap "this" to whatever is convenient.

Comment: So, the short answer to your question is that -- .NET simply **cannot** change "this" to point to your button.

Answer (score 1):

In C# the handlers are methods of the Form object and thus `this` also references this object.

However, I think you can use one of the handler's arguments to get the element related to the event.

Comment: yep. The `object source` parameter is equivalent to `this` in javascript.

Comment: +1 for source but is source really equivalent to this in js ?